# Command line utility to copy files based on their content and date

Tags: excel, batch-file, powershell, scripting, command-line-arguments

I have a list of more than 10,000 excel files in location A.

- I need a free utility  (since I need to use windows task scheduler to
  run this every x minutes) which will scan these files and search for
  a particular string/content in the file.
- The file should also be created/modified after a specific date.
- If the file meets these criteria then it must be copied to Location B.

I found a free program called `Ultrafile Search` which managed to identify the files but it does not run with parameters etc so i cannot use it in the scheduler. I also tried `WinGrep` which seemingly does what I require but it keeps on freezing all the time probably due to the amount of files. A command-line utility or a batch file script would be great. Thanks

Comment: Are these `.xlsx` files?

Comment: Batch/cmd cannot read `.xls` or `.xlsx` files.  You'll need to use a third party tool or a VBscript on a PC that has Excel installed as VBscript can expose the code to read Excel files.  Reading 10,000 files is going to be a pretty long task I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a basic skeleton. Adapt as needed.

This is a hybrid batch/jscript file (save as `.cmd`). It uses `robocopy` to first select the files in the indicated date range. The generated list is passed to the javascript part to filter for content of the excel file. The javascript acts as a filter and echoes only the file names with the indicated string inside. This list is retrieved/processed by a `for` command (in the sample it simply echoes the file name to console)

Of course, for it to work, it is necessary that excel is installed.

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "sourceFolder=%cd%"
    set "dateStart=20140709"
    set "searchString=testing"

    set "dateFilter=robocopy "%sourceFolder%" "%temp%" *.xls /l /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /maxage:%dateStart% "
    set "contentFilter=cscript //nologo //e:Javascript "%~f0" /search:"%searchString%" "

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (' %dateFilter% ^| %contentFilter% ') do (
        echo Selected file : [%%a]
    )

    endlocal
    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************

    // retrieve the string to search for
    var searchFor = WScript.Arguments.Named('search');

    // instantiate needed components
    var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    var excel = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');

    // iterate over the stdin reading file names to process
    while ( ! WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ){
        var fileName = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
        fileName = fileName.replace(/^\s*/g,'');
        fileName = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(fileName);
        if (fso.FileExists( fileName )){
            if (excelDataSearch( excel, fileName, searchFor )) {
                WScript.StdOut.WriteLine( fileName );
            };
        };
    };

    // if not needed, close the instantiated excel application
    if ( excel.WorkBooks.Count === 0 ) excel.Quit();

    // leave
    WScript.Quit(0);


function excelDataSearch( excel, workbook, searchString ){
    var returnValue = false ;

    try {
        // search for workbook application
        //var wb = GetObject( workbook );
        var wb = excel.Workbooks.Open( workbook, false, true );

        // iterate the worksheets of the workbook searching the string in its data
        var eWS = new Enumerator(wb.WorkSheets);
        for (; !eWS.atEnd() ; eWS.moveNext()){
            var ws = eWS.item();
            if ( ws.UsedRange.Cells.Find(searchString) ){
                returnValue = true ;
                break;
            };
        };

        // close workbook
        wb.Close( false );

    } catch(e){
            // some kind of problem with objects
            // WScript.Echo( e.description );
    };

    return returnValue;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`PowerShell` solution that

- finds all excel files under *c:\temp* recursively
- checks if they have been used since 1/1/2010
- checks cell A1 in sheet 1 equals a variable `str`,

and if so copies the file to a new directory (*c:\test*)

```
$newpath = "c:\test"
$str = "Test"
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.visible = $false

$excelSheets = Get-ChildItem c:\temp -recurse -include *.xls*  | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt “1/1/2010}

foreach($excelSheet in $excelSheets)
{
$workbook = $xl.Workbooks.Open($excelSheet)
$ws = $workbook.workSheets.Item(1)
$strxl = $ws.Cells.Item(1,1).Value2
$workbook.close()
if ($strxl -eq $str) {Copy-Item $excelsheet $newpath}
}#end foreach
$xl.quit()
$xl = $null
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```